# Azure DevOps Build : run command "OnCancel"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I use Azure DevOps to schedule jobs on Azure Batch AI. Launching of jobs works great, I have python code that does the same.

What I am trying to achieve is that all jobs in the Batch AI experiment should be terminated when the build is cancelled. Currently, cancelling the build doesn't affect the run status of the Batch AI jobs.

Hence, is there a sort of "OnCancel" event to hook on to in the build to run a command (which will be python code to terminate all jobs) ?

Comment: Does adding a Task, and configuring it to run even if all previous steps have failed work (i.e. `Run this task` set to `Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was cancelled`)

Comment: Thanks Brendan, that seems to be a possibility. Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=yaml. Feel free to create an answer, I'll verify if it works and mark it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to look for an event, as a pipeline task can be configured to execute where the build was cancelled.

Note: this applies (as far as I am aware) to **any** task of the pipeline:

[image: Run this task]

Specifically, the **Run this task** setting, under **Control Options** will let you dictate when and under what conditions a task will run.

In the example above, this task will execute **even if previous tasks fail**, and **even if the build was canceled**.

In your case, I would place this as the **last** task that will perform the cleanup that you want, regardless of the outcome of the build.